# Bokeh 0.12.14 + Flask: Broken library or new syntax for AjaxDataSource?

Tags: python, ajax, flask, bokeh

I find a strange behavior after installing the latest Bokeh library (0.12.14).

In the following example, a set of 180 values are randomly created upon Ajax request and visualized every second.

Version 0.12.13 works perfectly but 0.12.14 generates a JS error:

```
bokeh-0.12.14.min.js:1 undefined http://0.0.0.0:5011/undefined 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

As you can see, the endpoint is `http://0.0.0.0:5011/undefined` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:5011/data`.
When called directly, `http://0.0.0.0:5011/data` is there and returns the JSON data.
It looks like Ajax endpoint has been lost. **Is this a bug or a documented syntax change in the library?**

If you want to play with it, **don't forget to change the version in BOKEH_VERSION**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template_string

from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models.sources import AjaxDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#########################
BOKEH_VERSION = "0.12.13"   # <--- DON'T FORGET TO CHANGE HERE IF USING ANOTHER VERSION
#########################

html_template="""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Example</title>
            <link href="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-{bokeh_ver}.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">        
            <script src="http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-{bokeh_ver}.min.js"></script>
        </head>
    """.format(bokeh_ver=BOKEH_VERSION)

html_template += """
     <body>
            <h1>Working in Bokeh 0.12.13<br>and not working in 0.12.14</h1>
            <div id="example_plot"></div>

            {{ plot_div.plot_grid | safe}}
            {{ plot_script | safe}}

        </body>
    </html>
    """

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

app = Flask(__name__)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ExamplePlot:

    def __init__(self, app):

        self._data_source = None
        self.data_source_update()   # create the first set of dummy data for self.data_source

        self._ajax_data_source = AjaxDataSource(
            data_url="/data",
            data=self._data_source,
            polling_interval = 1000,
        )

        self.figure = figure()

        self.figure.line(
            source=self._ajax_data_source,
            x="index",
            y="value",
        )

    def data_source_update(self):
        self._data_source = {
            "index": range(180),
            "value": list(np.random.randint(1,100,size=180))
        }

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

example_plot = ExamplePlot(app)

@app.route("/")
def main_page():

    script, div = components({'plot_grid': example_plot.figure})

    html = render_template_string(
        html_template,
        plot_script = script,
        plot_div = div,
    )
    return html


@app.route("/data", methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST'])
def serve():
    example_plot.data_source_update()

    return jsonify(
        index=example_plot._data_source["index"],
        value=example_plot._data_source["value"],
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5011)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. There was a recent refactor of how selections are handled, and a necessary update to `AjaxDataSource` was missed. It will be fixed for `0.12.15`